# Is it possible to create a "negative" ACL?

Tags: permissions, acl

Is it possible to create an ACL to **deny** access to a specific user (say `jdoe`) to a specific file?

I'm not interested in the trivial solution of an ACL that gives access to the file to all users except `jdoe`. This solution has the disadvantage that any user created successively in the system won't have access to the file.

Creating a group of all users except `jdoe` and granting group access to the file bears the same disadvantage.

The command `setfacl -x u:jdoe /path/file` won't work as it removes only created ACLs.

Comment: how about seting the group ownership of the file to a group containing only this user and restricting access to group - with `chmod 0604`?

Comment: This won't work as the `other` permission (which is `r--`) applies, therefore `jdoe` will have read access to the file.

Comment: what you say is reasonable, but I just tried it and it works on my system (ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Near-duplicate: [Precedence of user and group owner in file permissions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134332/precedence-of-user-and-group-owner-in-file-permissions)

Comment: @dr01 No, other permissions do not apply if a more specific permission applies. User permissions are considered first, then group, then other. The first match applies, there is no “or” operation except within the group level.

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I just tested on a CentOS 7 machine and it works. @adonis, I'm going to accept Christopher's answer as the most correct one, but please write your comment as an answer so I can upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, to demonstrate, as root...

```
touch /tmp/test
setfacl -m u:jdoe:--- /tmp/test
getfacl /tmp/test
su - jdoe
cat /tmp/test
exit
rm /tmp/test
```

It could be done to every file in a directory by default as well:

```
mkdir /var/data/not-for-jdoe
setfacl -m u:jdoe:--- /var/data/not-for-jdoe
setfacl -d -m u:jdoe:--- /var/data/not-for-jdoe
```

Above, the `-m` switch is the mask and the `-d` switch makes it the default mask for all new filesystem objects in the directory. The `---` can have other permission values, e.g.:

- `rwx`
- `r--`
- `rw-`
- `r-x`
- `7`
- `4`
- `6`
- `5`

The group and other masks work the same way: `g:groupname:---` or in combination: `u:username:---,g:groupname:---,o::---`. Not specifying a username or group name applies the mask to current user/group ownership.

Answer (score -4):

`setfacl` is a command from the deprecated because withdrawn in 1997 POSIX ACL draft proposal that was never standardized.

`setfacl` cannot do this.

If you have a modern OS that supports NFSv4/NTFS ACLs, you can do this.
See e.g. http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/chmod.1.html

Check the examples starting at page 19.

This is for Solaris, but AIX and OSX also support NFSv4 ACLs.

Comment: Well, setfacl certainly can do what the OP wants it to do in Linux