# How to express `find`'s -writable and -readable tests, when they are not available?

Tags: files, permissions, find, search

Sometimes on old Linux systems, I experience that `find` doesn't support `-writable` and `-readable` tests, which test whether the file or directory is writable/readable resp. for the current user.

Say, I want to express `-writable`; then `-perm -0002` would not be equivalent, since it doesn't test whether the user has write permissions by means of owner/group.

How can I express `find`'s `-writable` test by means of `find`'s other tests (e.g. `-perm`)?

Comment: If you're talking about the deprecated -perm +mode option, cant you just check writable for user or group or others (0222) ?

Comment: See also [Find files that a user can write, efficiently with minimal process creation](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/203628) and [Using find in Solaris 10 to search a single directory but not its subdirectories](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/256991)

Comment: Also: [Find files that a user can not read?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/88573)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no convenient way. That's why GNU find added `-readable` and friends.

You can build an expression that approximates the permission test by enumerating the groups that the user is in. Untested.

```sh
can_access="( -user $(id -u) -perm -0${oct}00 -o ("
for g in $(id -G); do
  can_access="$can_access -group $g -o"
done
can_access="${can_access% -o} ) -perm -00${oct}0 -o -perm -000${oct} )"
find … $can_access -print
```

This doesn't give the correct result in some cases, for example if there are access control lists, or in edge cases such as `-rw----r--` to deny access to a group. You can check for the edge cases with the same technique as above, but the expression gets even more complex. For access control lists, you need to invoke a tool that supports them.

Languages such as Perl and Python provide easy access both to the `access(2)` function and to the functionality of `find`. In Perl, with [`File::Find`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) and [`-r`/`-w`/`-x`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#-X-EXPR) (which use the effective uid and gid of the Perl process — use `-R`/`-W`/`-X` to check with the real uid/gid like `access(2)`, and use the [`filetest 'access'` pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/filetest.html#The-%22access%22-sub-pragma) if your Perl isn't too ancient to have it to support things like ACL):

```perl
use File::Find;
use filetest 'access';
find(sub { if (-r $_) { print "$_ is readable\n"; } }, '.');
```

In Python, with [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and [`os.access`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) (which uses the real uid and gid of the Python process, like `access(2)`):

```python
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.', ):
    for filename in filenames:
        filename = os.path.join(dirpath, filenames)
        if os.access(filename, os.R_OK):
            print(filename + ' is readable\n')
```

The only fully reliable way is to try to open the file. This requires an external utility, so it'll be slower. To test for readability of a regular file:

```sh
find … -exec sh -c 'exec 2>/dev/null; : <"$0"' {} \; …
```

To test for writability, use `: >>"$0"` (this opens the file for appending, so it'll fail if the file isn't writable, but it doesn't actually modify anything, and in particular won't update the modification time). To test a directory for readability, use `ls -- "$0" >/dev/null`. To test a directory for executability, use `cd -- "$0"`.
There's no passive test for executability of a regular file, for writability of a directory, or for access to most non-regular files.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `!` was a typo. The edge case of `---rwxrwx` is similar to the slightly less rare edge case of `-rw----r--` which I discuss in my answer. I only propose `: >> "$0"` for regular files; as you note, for other file types such as dangling symbolic links (and pipes etc.), it doesn't work.

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer. So, I guess the short answer is that `-readable` and friends cannot completely be expressed using `find`'s other tests. I don't understand, why your test doesn't work for your edge case `-rw----r--`? In this case, `-perm -000${oct}` would yield true?

Comment: @Shuzheng A file with `-rw----r--` permissions owned by `someuser:somegroup` is readable to everyone except for members of the group `somegroup` who are not `someuser`. The simplified logic in my answer doesn't work if the calling user is a member of `somegroup` other than `someuser`: `-perm -0004` is true, because the file is readable to others, so my logic concludes that everyone can read the file, which is wrong. It's _possible_ to express the correct logic, but it's pretty long, and it still doesn't take access control lists into account.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I always thought that a user could read a file, if just any of the permissions for u/g/o allowed that - this is not true? Also, how can I see if ACL is enabled for a file by `ls`?

Comment: @Shuzheng The first match applies, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134332/precedence-of-user-and-group-owner-in-file-permissions/134376#134376 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353598/precedence-of-acls-when-a-user-belongs-to-multiple-groups/353629#353629 . `ls` shows `+` at the end of the permissions if there's an ACL, or a `.` if there's an SELinux (or similar) context.

Comment: thank you once again. FYI, your first answer link has several copy-paste typos wrt. permission bits and ACLs. Also, which man page would explain how u/g/o permissions are used?

Comment: @Shuzheng Can you please tell me where the typos are, or even better suggest an edit? For ugo permissions, I can't find that in a man page; [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_05)'s how POSIX describes it (I wouldn't say “explains it”, because it's in standardese: precise but hard to understand).